# checkSelfPermission function not accessing this as reference of current activivty

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

im giving reference of current activity using this pointer in checkSelfPermission method but this is showing following error

> 'checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)' in 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' cannot be applied to '(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.String)'

following is code lines

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){

            }
```

Comment: it did not work.... showing error that MainActivity.this is of int type instead of boolean.

Comment: if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this , Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
                    !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                }

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the reference of the onclick... use

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){

            }
```

Comment: this is also not working and showing following error   
Incompatible types. Found: 'int', required: 'boolean'

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = textmessage.getText().toString();
                String telno = texttelno.getText().toString();

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this , Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){

                }
            }

Comment: use this >> if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this ,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){}

Comment: i know i have to complete it yet but what should i do for above error